# Parse Nested JSON File in C++Builder

Tags: json, c++builder

I am using C++Builder 10.4.2 with the 64bit compiler. I am trying to parse the nested JSON file below so the `"US.NYSE"` values are in a `TJSONArray`, and then loop through them to get each array value. My code does not place the `"US.NYSE"` into an array. Can you show how to place `"US.NYSE"` into a `TJSONArray`? Currently, I can't test the `for` loop, is this `for` loop set up correct?

```json
{
  "data":{
    "US.NYSE":{
      "fin_id":"US.NYSE",
      "exchange":"New York Stock Exchange",
      "market":"Canonical",
      "products":null,
      "local_time":"2020-11-27T11:55:00-05:00",
      "status":"Open",
      "reason":"Market Holiday - Primary Trading Session (Partial)",
      "until":"2020-11-27T12:45:00-05:00",
      "next_bell":"2020-11-27T13:00:00-05:00"
    }
  }
}
```

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::Button33Click(TObject *Sender)
{

    UnicodeString s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9;

    std::unique_ptr<TStringStream> jsonstream(new TStringStream);
    jsonstream->LoadFromFile("marketstatus1.json");

    TJSONObject* MyjsonFile = (TJSONObject*)TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue(jsonstream->DataString);
    Application->MessageBoxW(MyjsonFile->ToString().w_str(), L"", 0);

    TJSONArray* MyjsonArray = (TJSONArray*)TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue(MyjsonFile->GetValue("data")->ToString());
    Application->MessageBoxW(MyjsonArray->ToString().w_str(), L"", 0);


    int TestCount = MyjsonArray->Count;

    for(int i=0; i<MyjsonArray->Count; i++){
        s1 = MyjsonArray->Items[i]->GetValue<UnicodeString>("fin_id");
        s2 = MyjsonArray->Items[i]->GetValue<UnicodeString>("exchange");
        s3 = MyjsonArray->Items[i]->GetValue<UnicodeString>("market");
        s4 = MyjsonArray->Items[i]->GetValue<UnicodeString>("products");
        s5 = MyjsonArray->Items[i]->GetValue<UnicodeString>("local_time");
        s6 = MyjsonArray->Items[i]->GetValue<UnicodeString>("status");
        s7 = MyjsonArray->Items[i]->GetValue<UnicodeString>("reason");
        s8 = MyjsonArray->Items[i]->GetValue<UnicodeString>("until");
        s9 = MyjsonArray->Items[i]->GetValue<UnicodeString>("next_bell");
    }

}
```

**Edit**

The code posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67613775/65863) works, except for the `GetValue()` method:

```cpp
s1 = MyjsonStock->GetValue<UnicodeString>(_D("fin_id"));
```

This gives the error in the `ustring.h` file:

> 'UnicodeString' does not refer to a value

This error jumps to line 28 of the `UnicodeString` class in `ustring.h`. I added the top of this file showing line 28 below. Can you recommend a change to the call of the `GetValue()` method?

```cpp
namespace System
{
  class                  TVarRec;
  class RTL_DELPHIRETURN Currency;
#if !defined(_DELPHI_NEXTGEN)
  class RTL_DELPHIRETURN WideString;
#endif
    
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // UnicodeString: String class compatible with Delphi's Native 'string' type
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  class RTL_DELPHIRETURN UnicodeString  //ERROR JUMPS HERE LINE(28)
  {
    friend UnicodeString operator +(const char*, const UnicodeString& rhs);
    friend UnicodeString operator +(const wchar_t*, const UnicodeString& rhs);
    friend UnicodeString operator +(const char16_t*, const UnicodeString& rhs);
    friend UnicodeString operator +(const char32_t*, const UnicodeString& rhs);

  public:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding of how JSON works. I suggest you review the syntax defined by  the JSON standard available at https://www.json.org.

There is **no array** in the JSON you have shown. Arrays are denoted with `[]` brackets. Objects are denoted with `{}` braces. So, the top-level JSON value is an Object, the `"data“` value is an Object, and the `"US.NYSE"` is an Object. Thus, the 2 `ParseJSONValue()` calls will both return a `TJSONObject`, not a `TJSONArray`.

There is no need to call `ParseJSONValue()` the 2nd time, since those inner `TJSONObject`s are already parsed by the 1st `ParseJSONValue()` call and are accessible inside of the value hierarchy of`MyjsonFile`. Simply typecast the return value of `GetValue()` to `TJSONObject*` when accessing those values.

Also, you need to `delete` the value that is returned by `ParseJSONValue()` to avoid a memory leak.

Try this instead:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::Button33Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  UnicodeString s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9;

  std::unique_ptr<TStringStream> jsonstream(new TStringStream);
  jsonstream->LoadFromFile(_D("marketstatus1.json"));

  std::unique_ptr<TJSONValue> MyjsonValue = TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue(jsonstream->DataString);

  TJSONObject* MyjsonFile = static_cast<TJSONObject*>(MyjsonValue.get());
  Application->MessageBoxW(MyjsonFile->ToString().c_str(), _D(""), 0);

  TJSONObject* MyjsonData = static_cast<TJSONObject*>(MyjsonFile->GetValue(_D("data")));
  Application->MessageBoxW(MyjsonData->ToString().c_str(), _D(""), 0);

  TJSONObject* MyjsonStock = static_cast<TJSONObject*>(MyjsonData->GetValue(_D("US.NYSE")));

  s1 = MyjsonStock->GetValue(_D("fin_id"))->Value();
  s2 = MyjsonStock->GetValue(_D("exchange"))->Value();
  s3 = MyjsonStock->GetValue(_D("market"))->Value();
  s4 = MyjsonStock->GetValue(_D("products"))->Value();
  s5 = MyjsonStock->GetValue(_D("local_time"))->Value();
  s6 = MyjsonStock->GetValue(_D("status"))->Value();
  s7 = MyjsonStock->GetValue(_D("reason"))->Value();
  s8 = MyjsonStock->GetValue(_D("until"))->Value();
  s9 = MyjsonStock->GetValue(_D("next_bell"))->Value();
}
```

Comment: The code you posted worked except for the call to GetValue method. I edited the original question above to add the needed information.  Can you suggest a change to the GetValue call. Thanks.

Comment: The code looks fine to me, based on the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONValue.GetValue).  But honestly, I never use the template version of `GetValue()`, I would just use the [non-templated version](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONObject.GetValue) instead. I have updated my answer to show this.